# Can I convert my Cython code to Python?

Tags: python, cython

I have written a cython code to help bridge the gap between a 3rdparty library and python.

I also written some of my code in cython to improve its performance.

Can I convert both of my above use cases into raw python?

example of use case one

```
def f(double x):
    return x**2-x

def integrate_f(double a, double b, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double s, dx
    s = 0
    dx = (b-a)/N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a+i*dx)
    return s * dx
```

example of use case 2

```
from libc.stdlib cimport atoi

cdef parse_charptr_to_py_int(char* s):
    assert s is not NULL, "byte string value is NULL"
    return atoi(s)   # note: atoi() has no error detection!
```

Answer (score 2):

Well for you first use case the answer is yes.
All you would need to do is remove the `cdef` lines like so.

```
def f(double x):
    return x**2-x

def integrate_f(double a, double b, int N):
    s = 0
    dx = (b-a)/N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a+i*dx)
    return s * dx
```

For your second use case that's where things get tricky because you cant just delete the `cdef` lines or rename `cdef` to `def`. Also since this use case depends on the external library it doesn't have direct to python translation.

You have 2 options you can use besides Cython.

- ctypes - the foreign function library built into standard python
- cffi - a library that works similar to ctypes but simplifies the library glue code.

Your usage example using ctypes would look like this

```
def parse_charptr_to_py_int(test):
    from ctypes import cdll,c_char_p
    cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so")
    return cdll.libc.atoi(c_char_p(test))
```

Your usage example using cffi would look like this

```
def parse_charptr_to_py_int(test):
    from cffi import FFI
    ffi = FFI()
    ffi.cdef("int atoi(const char *str);")
    CLib = ffi.dlopen("libc.so")
    return CLib.atoi(test)
```